# What are the recent TCS books whose drafts are available online?

Tags: reference-request, big-list, books

Following the post [What Books Should Everyone Read](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/what-books-should-everyone-read), I noticed that there are recent books whose drafts are available online.

For instance, the [Approximation Algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/what-books-should-everyone-read/3466#3466) entry of the above post cites a 2011 book (yet to be published) titled [The design of approximation algorithms](http://www.designofapproxalgs.com/).

I think knowing recent works is really useful for whoever wants to get a taste of TCS trends. When drafts are available, one can check the books before actually buying them.

So,

> What are the recent TCS books whose drafts are available online?

Here, by "recent", I mean something that's no older than ~5 years.

Comment: I have flagged it for becoming CW.

Comment: It would be nice if the answers turn into CW also so we can up-vote them.

Comment: answers become CW by default if the question is CW.

Comment: @Suresh: But we have already non-CW answers and they should be turned into CW, too.

Comment: @Suresh and @Jukka, how do I CWize my answer?

Comment: @Alessandro Cosentino: click edit under your answer and then check the check-box for CW.

Comment: See also Radu Grigore's answer for semantics books: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3533/books-on-programming-language-semantics/3544#3544

Comment: @Kaveh, @Suresh, @Jukka: Maybe we should have a policy of converting all answers to CW once a question has been made CW? (Can moderators make answers CW too, or does the original poster have to do that?)

Comment: @Robin: It sounds reasonable but in general CW issues are not completely resolved for me and I would like to discuss CW more generally, so I started a [meta discussion](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/759/new-community-wiki-policy).

Answer (score 45):

Several TCS books by [Now Publishers](http://www.nowpublishers.com/product.aspx?product=TCS) can be found in drafts:

- [Foundations of Cryptography– A Primer](http://www.nowpublishers.com/product.aspx?product=TCS&doi=0400000001) by Oded Goldreich. This is a summarized version of his famous two-volume book on cryptography. (The draft of the two-volume version can be found in [Robin's answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-are-the-recent-tcs-books-whose-drafts-are-available-online/3556#3556).)
- [Data Streams: Algorithms and Applications](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~muthu/stream-1-1.ps) by S. Muthukrishnan.
- [Mathematical Aspects of Mixing Times in Markov Chains](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~tetali/PUBLIS/survey.pdf) by Montenegro & Tetali.
- [Pairwise Independence and Derandomization](http://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/BOOKS/TCS003-1.pdf) by Luby & Widgerson.
- [Average-Case Complexity](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs.CC/0606037) by Bogdanov & Trevisan.
- [A Survey of Lower Bounds for Satisfiability and Related Problems](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.114.3402) by Melkebeek.
- [Algorithms and Data Structures for External Memory](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jsv/Papers/Vit.IO_book.pdf) by Vitter.
- [Probabilistic Proof Systems: A Primer](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/pps-primer.html) by Goldreich. Again, this is a summarized version of a part Goldreich's book [Modern Cryptography, Probabilistic Proofs and Pseudorandomness](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/book1.html).
- [The Design of Competitive Online Algorithms via a Primal-Dual Approach](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/nivbuchb/papers/pd-survey.pdf) by Buchbinder & Naor.
- [Spectral Algorithms](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vempala/spectralbook.pdf) by Kannan & Vempala.
- [On the Power of Small-Depth Computation](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/viola/papers/shallow.pdf) by Viola.
- [Algorithmic and Analysis Techniques in Property Testing](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/PDF/dana-tech.pdf) by Ron.
- [Arithmetic Circuits: A Survey of Recent Results and Open Questions](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~shpilka/publications/SY10.pdf)
  by Amir Shpilka and Amir Yehudayoff (2010), Foundations and Trends® in Theoretical Computer Science: Vol. 5: No. 3–4, pp 207-388. http://dx.doi.org/10.1561/0400000039

---

In addition, drafts of several [Springer books on "Information Security and Cryptography"](http://www.springer.com/series/4752?detailsPage=titles) can be found online:

- [Cryptography in Constant Parallel Time](http://www.eng.tau.ac.il/~bennyap/pubs/thesis.pdf) by Applebaum.
- [A Study of Statistical Zero-Knowledge Proofs](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/cis/theses/salil-phd.ps) by Vadhan.
- [Locally Decodable Codes and Private Information Retrieval Schemes](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/42242) by Yekhanin.
- [Concurrent Zero Knowledge](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~alon/PAPERS/thesis/thesis.ps) by Rosen.

Answer (score 38):

Arora and Barak [Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/complexity/) , 2010.

Comment: A warning. the draft is really just that: a draft. There are numerous errors in the draft that got fixed in the printed version (I know this because I ran a summer reading group using the draft and had to constantly correct it from the book)

Comment: The book is really worth buying. Not expensive at all for its value and size.

Answer (score 37):

<strike>[Algorithms](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/all.pdf) by S. Dasgupta, C.H. Papadimitriou, and U.V. Vazirani</strike>

EDIT (Sept 16 '15): The link is broken, I believe the draft is no longer available online.

Comment: The link is broken as of 12/10/2013. Perhaps the online access is no longer available?

Comment: @LoganMayfield that's strange, because you can still access the single chapters here: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/

Comment: Here is a link for the book http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~naveen/courses/CSL630/all.pdf

Answer (score 35):

Let me add the following:

[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/anacombi.html), by Flajolet and Sedgewick

<strike>[Codes and Automata](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/LivreCodes/Old/newlivreCodesOld.pdf)</strike>  (Link Broken), by Berstel, Perrin and Reutenauer

Answer (score 32):

[Oded Goldreich](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/books.html) has several drafts available for download on his webpage.

- [Computational Complexity: A Conceptual Perspective (2008)](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/cc-drafts.html)
- [P, NP, and NP-Completeness: The Basics of Complexity Theory (2010)](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/bc-drafts.html)
- [The Foundations of Cryptography (2001 and 2004)](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/foc-drafts.html)
- [A Primer on Pseudorandom Generators (2010)](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/PDF/prg10.pdf)
- [Introduction to Property Testing (2017)](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/pt-intro.html)

Answer (score 27):

[Reinhard Diestel's Graph Theory](http://diestel-graph-theory.com/) (4th edition, 2010), in a variety of electronic formats.

Answer (score 27):

Sariel Har-Peled has an upcoming book on Geometric Approximation Algorithms. It has been
available in draft form as lecture notes for a while now.

http://valis.cs.uiuc.edu/~sariel/teach/notes/aprx/

Comment: arggh. how on earth did I forget that one !

Comment: @Suresh: (Just kidding) A senior moment, perhaps ;)

Comment: arggh. more like a lack-of-coffee moment :)

Comment: And it is no longer available online - the publication date is getting nearer, and I promised the publisher (AMS) not to put it online. Sorry...

Answer (score 25):

[Expander Graphs and their applications](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~nati/PAPERS/expander_survey.pdf), by Hoory, Linial and Wigderson. This is verging on monograph territory at 123 pages.

Answer (score 25):

[Boolean Function Complexity: Advances and Frontiers](http://www.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~jukna/BFC.html) by Stasys Jukna.

[(Preface)](http://www.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~jukna/pref.html) [(Table of Contents)](http://www.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~jukna/TOC.html)

A free draft used to be available as a direct download a while ago (if I remember correctly), but now it seems you can obtain it by filling out a form on his webpage or emailing him.

Comment: On the topic of Boolean functions and Fourier analysis: [Analysis of Boolean Functions](http://analysisofbooleanfunctions.org/), by Ryan O'Donnell (2014): the pdf version is available [here](http://get.analysisofbooleanfunctions.org/).

Answer (score 24):

Stephen Cook & Phuong Nguyen published a book named [Logical Foundations of Proof Complexity](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item2708116/?site_locale=en_GB) in March 2010. There is a draft on Cook's website: [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sacook/homepage/book/). Unfortunately, I haven't read it.

Comment: Chapter 2 itself is already a very elegant introduction to propositional logic and first order logic, with important tools like Completeness, Compactness,  Löwenheim–Skolem, and Hebrand's Theorem.

Comment: I've read many parts of the book, and I highly recommend it for people interested in complexity and logic. For people working in proof complexity I think it's possibly a must. It does not deal with proof complexity lower bounds, which is the major issue of the topic, but it gives the essential logical context of proof complexity.  It is especially suited for beginners, and for self study. Literally, no prior knowledge is assumed, everything is explained from scratch and full details are provided for everything. (Also, the draft is almost the same as the book.)

Answer (score 22):

[Markov Chains and Mixing Times](http://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/) by D.A. Levin, Y. Peres, E.L. Wilmer (2008). Finally a text book covering this broad and ubiquitous topic.

Comment: now that's a nice book.

Answer (score 21):

There is a new upcoming book on [Spectral Algorithms](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vempala/spectralbook.html) by Ravi Kannan and Santosh Vempala covering several latest developments. It covers several applications of spectral methods, algorithms for estimating spectral parameters and low rank approximation of matrices.

Answer (score 20):

Since Suresh Venkat mentioned the monograph on expanders, I will also mention the following related monographs on the topic of *pseudorandomness*. The draft of [Pseudorandomness](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/pseudorandomness/) by Salil Vadhan (220 pages) is very worth reading. The monograph [Parwise Independence and Derandomization](http://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/BOOKS/TCS003-1.pdf) by Luby and Wigderson is also nice!

Answer (score 18):

The books in open access from the [site](http://library.msri.org/books/) of Mathematical Sciences Research Institute:

- Volume 56, [Games of No Chance 3](http://library.msri.org/books/Book56/index.html), edited by Michael H. Albert and Richard J. Nowakowski, 2009.
- Volume 52, [Combinatorial and Computational Geometry](http://library.msri.org/books/Book52/index.html), edited by Jacob E. Goodman, János Pach and Emo Welzl, 2005.
- Volume 44, [Algorithmic Number Theory](http://library.msri.org/books/Book44/index.html), edited by Joe Buhler and Peter Stevenhagen, 2008.
- Volume 42, [More Games of No Chance](http://library.msri.org/books/Book42/index.html), edited by Richard J. Nowakowski, 2002.
- Volume 29, [Games of No Chance](http://library.msri.org/books/Book29/index.html), edited by Richard Nowakowski, 1996.

Here I have listed only those books which to me best fit in the definition of TCS.

NB. Books are not drafts and were published.

Comment: Wow, excellent source!

Answer (score 16):

[The discrepancy method](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/book.html), Bernard Chazelle.

[Probability on Trees and Networks](http://mypage.iu.edu/~rdlyons/prbtree/prbtree.html), Russell Lyons with Yuval Peres

Both are great reads! You might want to grab Lyons-Peres now before they take it offline.

Answer (score 15):

Book by Bruno Courcelle "[Graph structure and monadic second-order logic, a language theoretic approach](http://www.labri.fr/perso/courcell/Book/TheBook.pdf)".

Answer (score 13):

[Algorithmic Game Theory](http://www.cambridge.org/journals/nisan/downloads/Nisan_Non-printable.pdf), by Noam Nisan, Tim Roughgarden, Eva Tardos, and Vijay V. Vazirani (2007).

Answer (score 12):

[Modern Computer Arithmetic](http://wwwmaths.anu.edu.au/~brent/pub/pub226.html) by R. P. Brent and P. Zimmermann.

Answer (score 12):

Hubert Comon, Max Dauchet, Remi Gilleron, Florent Jacquemard, Denis Lugiez, Christof Löding, Sophie Tison, Marc Tommasi: [Tree Automata Techniques and Applications](http://tata.gforge.inria.fr/)

Answer (score 12):

"Descriptive Complexity, Canonisation, and Definable Graph Structure Theory," by Martin Grohe. Date on manuscript: March 7, 2013. Available at: <strike>http://www.automata.rwth-aachen.de/~grohe/pub.en.</strike> (Link Broken)

Answer (score 11):

[Spectra of Graphs](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/2WF02/spectra.pdf) by [Brouwer](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/) and [Haemers](http://lyrawww.uvt.nl/~haemers/home.html). I came to this book by way of [Chapter 16](http://cs-www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/PAPERS/SGTChapter.pdf) (written by Spielman) in [Combinatorial Scientific Computing](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781439827352).

Answer (score 11):

"Models of Computation, Exploring the Power of Computing," by John E. Savage. Available at http://www.cs.brown.edu/~jes/book/pdfs/ModelsOfComputation.pdf.

Answer (score 11):

Automata Theory: An Algorithmic Approach 
by Javier Esparza

http://www7.in.tum.de/~esparza/automatanotes.html

Answer (score 10):

There is an online draft of the new book "Iterative Methods in Combinatorial Optimization" by Lap Chi Lau, R. Ravi, and Mohit Singh:

http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~mohit/book/book.html

It is about the iterative rounding method: a new techhnique that can be used to design approximation algorithms for many problems.

Answer (score 10):

Notes or books about Distributed Algorithms:

- "A Course on Deterministic Distributed Algorithms" by Jukka Suomela. Available at http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/josuomel/dda/dda-print.pdf
- "Principles of Distributed Computing" by Roger Wattenhofer. Available at http://dcg.ethz.ch/lectures/podc_allstars/lecture/podc.pdf

Answer (score 10):

"Logic and Discrete Mathematics for Computer Scientists", by James Caldwell. Manuscript Date: August 22, 2011. Available at: http://www.cs.uwyo.edu/~jlc/courses/2300/book.pdf.

"Data Structures and Algorithms, The Basic Toolbox", by Kurt Mehlhorn. Manuscript Date: August 2008. Available at: http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/ftp/Toolbox/.

"An Introduction to Graph Theory and Complex Networks", by Martin Van Steen. Manuscript Date: January 2010. Available at: http://www.distributed-systems.net.

"Category Theory for Computing Science," by Michael Barr and Charles Wells. Available at http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/22/tr22.pdf.

"Philosophy of Computer Science," by William J. Rappaport. Manuscript Date: December 24, 2013. Available at: http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~rapaport/Papers/phics.pdf.

"Fractional Graph Theory: A Rational Approach To The Theory Of Graphs," by Edward Scheinerman And Daniel Ullman. Available at http://www.ams.jhu.edu/~ers/fgt/fgt.pdf.

Answer (score 10):

"Foundations of Data Science" ([pdf](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/jeh/book.pdf)) by Hopcroft and Kannan. The text was [discussed by Lipton](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2013/12/09/a-negative-impossibility-theorem/) on his blog.  As the title implies, the emphasis of the text seems to be applications and issues related to Big Data and Learning problems.  It seems to have grown out of [this course](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/CStheory-infoage/).

(Update 8/2015) The book now has a third author, Avrim Blum. The pdf link has been updated.

Comment: newer version: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/jeh/book112013.pdf

Comment: and I think the title is Foundations of Data Science.

Comment: Updated the link to the April 2014 version found on Hopcroft's website.

Answer (score 8):

[PlanetMath](http://planetmath.org/?op=listobj&from=books) lists over 150 books which are available online. The list is updated regularly (the most recent addition being 2011-01-09, as of this writing).
Books are math-related, but some of them are useful in TCS, too.

Comment: link please? I couldn't find that list on PlanetMath...

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow: Unfortunately, the old link I provided above no longer works. I'll replace it as soon as I find the new link.

Answer (score 7):

[Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.Textbook), by David Barber.

Answer (score 6):

Networks, Crowds, and Markets: Reasoning About a Highly Connected World by David Easley and Jon Kleinberg.

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/networks-book/

Answer (score 6):

Devdatt Dubhashi and Alessandro Panconesi: Concentration of Measure for the Analysis of Randomised Algorithms. A first draft is available at http://wwwusers.di.uniroma1.it/~ale/Papers/master.pdf (via geomblog)

Answer (score 4):

Rajaraman A., Leskovec J., and Ullman J.D. - [Mining of Massive Datasets](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds.html)

Answer (score 4):

[Parameterized Algorithms](http://parameterized-algorithms.mimuw.edu.pl/parameterized-algorithms.pdf) by Marek Cygan, Fedor V. Fomin, Łukasz Kowalik, Daniel Lokshtanov, Dániel Marx, Marcin Pilipczuk, Michał Pilipczuk, and Saket Saurabh.

Answer (score 3):

**Introduction to Theoretical Computer Science**

*Boaz Barak*

https://introtcs.org/public/index.html

Answer (score 2):

These 3 books on arithmetic complexity don't seem to have been mentioned till now,

- (Amir Shpilka, Amir Yehudayoff)
  http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~shpilka/publications/SY10.pdf
- (Xi Chen, Neeraj Kayal, and Avi Wigderson)        http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=154351
- (Neeraj Kayal and Ramprasad Saptharishi)   http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=212431

Some recent books on learning theory

- (Toby Segaran) http://edc.tversu.ru/elib/inf/0251.pdf
- (Hastie-Tisbshirani-Friedman)
            http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/
- (Rakhlin-Sridharan)
  http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~sridharan/lecnotes.pdf
- (Hazan) Online convex optimization: http://ocobook.cs.princeton.edu/

Comment: Kayal-Saptharishi is just a survey, not a book. The other two are essentially "survey monographs", which are somewhere in between books and "just surveys," but I suppose they should count, esp. because they are some of the only free book-like expositions of algebraic circuits... :)

Answer (score 2):

**Tutorials on the Foundations of Cryptography** (edited by Yehuda Lindell)

*Dedicated to Oded Goldreich*

From the [Springer page](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319570471):

> Advanced tutorials developed by Benny Applebaum, Boaz Barak, Andrej Bogdanov, Iftach Haitner, Shai Halevi, Yehuda Lindell, Alon Rosen, and Salil Vadhan
>
> Domain and authors inspired by Oded Goldreich, a pioneering scientist, educator and mentor
>
> Appropriate for graduate tutorials and seminars, and for self-study by experienced researchers

5 of the 7 chapters (so far) are available online, on ECCC.

- [Chapter 1 (ECCC TR17-067)](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2017/067/): Garbled Circuits as Randomized Encodings of Functions: a Primer (Benny Applebaum)
- [Chapter 2 (ECCC TR17-065)](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2017/065/): The Complexity of Public-Key Cryptography (Boaz Barak)
- [Chapter 3 (ECCC TR17-113)](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2017/113/): Pseudorandom Functions: Three Decades Later (Andrej Bogdanov, Alon Rosen)
- [Chapter 4 (ECCC TR17-084)](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2017/084/): The Many Entropies in One-Way Functions (Iftach Haitner and Salil Vadhan)
- [Chapter 6 (ECCC TR17-112)](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2017/112/): How To Simulate It — A Tutorial on the Simulation Proof Technique (Yehuda Lindell)

Answer (score 2):

Jan Krajíček's [Proof Complexity](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/prfdraft.html). It not only has lower bound but also upper bound and beyond.

Answer (score 2):

Venkatesan Guruswami, Atri Rudra, Madhu Sudan. [Essential Coding Theory](https://cse.buffalo.edu/faculty/atri/courses/coding-theory/book/web-coding-book.pdf), 2019.

Answer (score 2):

A bit awkward as it's my own, but the draft of my monograph on distribution testing, ["Topics and Techniques in Distribution Testing: A Biased but Representative Sample"](https://www.nowpublishers.com/article/Details/CIT-114) (Now Publishers, FnT CIT, 2022) is available online here:

- https://ccanonne.github.io/survey-topics-dt.html (direct link to PDF [here](https://ccanonne.github.io/files/misc/main-survey-fnt.pdf))

This includes the [solutions to the exercises](https://ccanonne.github.io/files/misc/main-survey-exercises.pdf).

Also, if you want the LaTeX source, you can find it here:

- https://github.com/ccanonne/survey-dt-fnt-cit

Answer (score 1):

The following book is about Database Theory, a small subarea of TCS at the border to Data Management:
[Principles of Databases by Marcelo Arenas, Pablo Barcelo, Leonid Libkin, Wim Martens, and Andreas Pieris.](https://github.com/pdm-book/community)

Answer (score -2):

[Foundations of Data Science](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/kannan/book-dec-30-2013.pdf) by John Hopcroft and Ravindran Kannan. It's an amazing book on Algorithms for Big Data Analytics. They call it the 21st century algorithms.

Comment: It is already mentioned: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/20164