# TCS online library

Tags: soft-question, books

My question isn't really related to TCS itself, it's more about technical and informational equipment of a computer scientist.

There is a website [SafariBooksOnline](http://safaribooksonline.com) by O'Reilly Media where anyone can read lots of books about IT online for a per-month payment. 
That's why you don't need to buy expensive books if you want just to run through a chapter and look through the content briefly. And you still can read it all if you feel yourself comfortable reading large book from a screen being constantly connected to the Internet.

Are there such websites with TCS books or science books in general?

Comment: I'm not aware of a single repository, but the closest is in fact the set of answers to this question: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-are-the-recent-tcs-books-whose-drafts-are-available-online

Comment: No there isn't. And that makes it very cool startup idea! ;-)

Comment: Thank you, Suresh, I've seen this question before, but that list has just a small number of books, mostly drafts actually.

Comment: TheMachineCharmer, yes, it surely does. But, as I believe, wide science publishing relations are crucial for a startup like this. And that's what stops me from evolving this idea, actually.

Comment: [Google Books](http://books.google.com/) allows reading (a limited number of pages) from lots of books, which is very useful. An if you are interested in a specific topic, then there are usually some online references listed on the Wikipedia page for the topic.

Comment: Digital Library+ (DL+) is a service that enables browsing and searching Databases, E-Journals, E-Books & References in their digital library (www.digitallibraryplus.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://gen.lib.rus.ec/

It has a relatively big selection of CS books, including lots of TCS books.

A few random examples:

Knuth (TAOCP and many other books): gen.lib.rus.ec/search?req=knuth&nametype=orig

Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein, Introduction to algorithms: gen.lib.rus.ec/search?req=cormen+leiserson+rivest+stein+introduction&nametype=orig

Sipser, Introduction to the theory of computation: gen.lib.rus.ec/search?req=sipser&nametype=orig

Hennessy, Patterson, Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach: gen.lib.rus.ec/search?req=hennessy+patterson&nametype=orig

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't add real links because of StackExchange's brain-damaged spam protection…

Comment: There's some question as to whether this site has legal copies of books are not.

Comment: @Suresh: Legal in which jurisdiction?

Comment: in the US, I imagine

Comment: @Suresh: Well, TCS SE is a very diverse community and certainly not everybody here lives or resides in the US, hence I don't see any reason why we should emphasize the US laws.

Comment: I have started a meta discussion: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/879/should-we-permit-linking-to-illegal-stuff

Comment: I am guessing the laws of the geographic area where the servers are hosted would somehow come into play... Of course, just a guess.