# What are CS blogs for puzzles/games?

Tags: soft-question

I am looking for blogs which contains recent progress on puzzles/games (Algebraic and Combinatorial) etc. like Soduko, latin square etc. I come across a list on TCS [What CS blogs should everyone read?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22191/what-cs-blogs-should-everyone-read), but it does not seem to contain the type of blogs I am looking for. I am looking for blogs that contains content related to the complexity and algorithmic question of games/puzzles.

I have tried to try to search on the internet. I have got a few resources like FUN conference etc., that helps to some extent.

Are there any blogs or webpage which can serve the purpose I have given below?

What I am from them

- Brief idea of the puzzle
- Current status of the puzzle
- Current open/interesting question on puzzle

Comment: There is some stuff on [my blog](http://www.nearly42.org) ... (though in the last year I temporarily abandoned my research on puzzle games)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- http://www.cseblog.com/
- [CMU - The Puzzle Toad](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/puzzle/)
- [Tanya Khovanova’s Math Blog](http://blog.tanyakhovanova.com/)

And the links therein.