# Resource for Understanding this Notation

Tags: pl.programming-languages

I am trying to read this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00925.
I am familiar with grammars, but I cannot understand the notations in figure 1. Can anyone suggest a resource or book where I can learn these notations? Here is what figure 1 looks like:
[image]
I understand that the first part is specifying the grammar. But I don't understand the rest like what is $e[x/v]$?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your post to include the notation you are asking about?  (E.g., a snapshot of part of that figure, with attribution.)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a research-level question to me.

Comment: This is the wrong forum to ask such questions. I recommend asking on cs.stackexchange.com, where someone's going to recommend [TAPL](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) to you.

Comment: Did you mean the BNF syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading a good textbook on the principles of programming language design, including semantics, e.g., Nielson & Nielson's textbook.  See also [natural deduction rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction) (e.g., https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/62679/755), first-order logic, and variable renaming.  See [Books on programming language semantics](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3533/5038).  $e[x/v]$ represents substitution; $x$ is replaced by $v$ in $e$.  This should all be covered by a good textbook.