# Texts on application of randomized algorithms

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, randomized-algorithms, books

as far as I know, Motwani & Raghavan, ”[Randomized Algorithms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521474655)”, Cambridge University Press, 1995 is the standard book for randomized algorithms. This is an excellent theoretical intro.

Which is another book (or book containing chapters) on applied randomized algorithms, especially on image processing, bioinformatics or pattern matching.

Thanks,
Lucian

Comment: @Imsasu: Welcome, you may find this relevant: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/what-books-should-everyone-read/3260#3260, and help extending the list after you get some good answers!

Comment: Nick Harvey has a course on Randomized Algorithms. You could have a look at the recommended reading list he provides, which is broken down by topic. http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~harvey/W11/

Comment: Can you change the title of the question to make it more informative?

Comment: Three users have voted to close this question as a duplicate of [What Books Should Everyone Read?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/what-books-should-everyone-read), but I do not agree that it is a duplicate.

Comment: I also agree that this is not a duplicate: the key point is 'applied'