# Where to find the latest book releases on theoretical computer science?

Tags: books

I was wondering if there is an online source where I can find the latest book releases on theoretical computer science issues?

And I mean quality books and papers on new and upcoming issues from famous authors. The amazon and other mainstream pages seem not to tend to those insider tip books I am searching for. Although I know there are famous best books out there as well.

They can also be written in a not so scientific and educational way as well. The specification is, so to say, to present the knowledge in the best known way.

You are also invited to comment this question with titles of the latest or "best" books on algorithms which you would recommend (I am looking for them at the moment).

*I hope this question belongs to this board somehow - sorry if not.*

Comment: Welcome to cstheory, a Q&A site for research-level questions in theoretical computer science (TCS). Your question does not appear to be a research-level question in TCS. Please see the [FAQ](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.
Perhaps [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com) is a better Q&A site for your question. However I bought the latest edition of many (really good) books on advanced topics on Amazon :-)... for the latest research issues take a look to the many TCS journals  or simply make a Google search to find research papers on the subject

Comment: :) I am sure, that you are able to buy all the books on amazon. My problem is merely, to find a good overview. So google was my choice before I posted this question. I thought there might be sombody out there, who has already collected/assambled such book titles and services them from time to time ...

Comment: can I move this question to the CS board anyhow?

Comment: I think that [this list from Lance Fortnow is GREAT](http://www.amazon.com/Favorite-Computational-Complexity-Books/lm/22R1UX0Y9YRT2/ref=cm_srch_res_rpli_alt_1), and you can also take a look to [this question on cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/what-books-should-everyone-read).

Comment: You can simply click "flag", and let the moderators know you'd like the question to be migrated to [CS.SE].

Comment: :) and it's an amazon list. cool

Comment: a great resource if it existed. there is a big difference between _classic_ books (in link) and _recent books_. all the publishers tend to have lists incl recent releases but not stdized (one would have to hunt for each publisher). dont know of a way to do it in general. dont know of a review column for recent books but some cs societies/mags have a book review column. there is a very good Notices AMS book review column that sometimes covers recent CS books. bloggers sometimes cover recent books. see the [TCS feed](http://feedworld.net/toc/) known by insiders, it will sometimes cover books.

Comment: ACM SIGACT News has a book review section. Other SIGs have their own.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi this can't be moved to the CS.SE board, because it would be off-topic there. They (like most SEs, but unlike cstheory) [don't accept list questions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14308954#14308954). helle, please revise your question to distinguish it from ["What books should everyone read?"](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3253/1037), and then we can better judge if it is a duplicate or on-topic here. Remember that cstheory focuses on _research-level_ questions, or at least on questions of general interest to researchers.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev I would say it's no duplicate to that question, because I am looking for recent books and so for recent and future issues in computer science. kind of, to hang in there.

Comment: unfortunately the question (subjectively) fails as too broad to ask for specific books (there are too many) and also does not define "recent". brainstorming, you might possibly ask for "lists of recent books of leading CS publishers maintained by the publishers..." ... another option is to try out underutilized [chat] here or elsewhere eg cs.se... you could try [meta] and ask for a collaborative effort to construct such a question... think it has some value & might be able to contribute something...

Comment: I guess Stackoverflow is also there to improve questions, so thanks for that @vzn