# Prerequisites for theoretical computer science

Tags: quantum-information

I am a freshman and a  Computer Science major,I have a very poor understanding in the area of electrical and electronics.I want to pursue a career in theoretical computer science esp. Quantum computing.So does my above weakness pose a barrier and prevent me from pursuing a career in Theoretical CS.
Also what qualities/prerequisites are required for pursuing a career in the above field.
Any person(in the area of quantum computing/theoretical CS)please advise me how to proceed?
..............Thank you............

Comment: Have you used the search functionality on the site? This question will be helpful in what books you can read about TCS: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/what-books-should-everyone-read

Comment: Aside from basic math and language skills, lack of knowledge in some area is not a barrier if you haven't even started college yet. At least if your college has a reasonable selection of courses and a decent library. Find your academic advisors and talk to them.

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for [cs.se].

Answer (score 1):

If your interests in theoretical computer science lie in quantum computing, a "poor" understanding of electronics should not prevent you at all from getting started. During your undergraduate studies, you may want to focus on courses like theory of computing, complexity theory, linear algebra and algorithms. Taking an introduction to quantum mechanics course from the physics or applied math department would also be beneficial. Many universities offer an undergraduate or low-level graduate course in quantum information/computing. If yours does not offer one, look at the [EdX course by Umesh Vazirani](https://www.edx.org/course/uc-berkeleyx/uc-berkeleyx-cs-191x-quantum-mechanics-1033#.U9ZeeYBdWdo), a pioneer of the field. There are also a few standard textbooks with a CS focus, like Nielsen & Chuang and Kaye, Laflamme and Mosca.